# Comparing values of different rows in a subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to pull back some data and having trouble with a query.

I have two tables:

Contact

- Contact_ID

Enrollment

- Start_Date
- End_Date
- Owning_Contact_ID
- Product_ID
- Enrollment_ID

This is a one to many relationship, where each contact has 0 to N Enrollments.  I want to find the latest (in terms of start date) two enrollments for each contact and only return them if the difference between enrollment1's start date (the latest start date) and enrollment2's end date (the second to latest start date) is greater than 1 day or the product_id is different between these two enrollment spans.

My original idea was to just join in two instances of the enrollment table, but this is slow and takes a long time.  Is there a better way?

Query:

```
 select * from contact CONT with (nolock)
            INNER JOIN Enrollment ENROLL1 with (nolock)
            on (ENROLL1.Enrollment_ID =
            (SELECT TOP 1 EN.Enrollment_ID FROM Enrollment EN WITH(NOLOCK) 
                where EN.Contact_id = CONT.Contact_Id
                                     order by EN.start_date desc)
            INNER JOIN Enrollment ENROLL2 with (nolock)
            on (ENROLL2.Enrollment_ID =
            (SELECT TOP 1 EN2.Enrollment_ID FROM Enrollment EN2 WITH(NOLOCK) 
                where EN2.Contact_id = CONT.Contact_Id
                                     order by EN2.start_date desc)
                             where Enroll1.Product_ID != Enroll2.Product_ID
```

(I never started working on the date difference bit because I was trying to get the above to work first before adding it in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the most recent 2 enrollments by doing:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by contact_id order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from enrollment e
     ) e
where seqnum <= 2;
```

You can get the summary information you need, using conditional aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select contact_id
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by contact_id order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from enrollment e
     ) e
where seqnum <= 2
group by contact_id
having min(productid) <> max(productid) or
       max(start_date) > dateadd(day, 1, min(start_date))
```

If you want additional information about the contact, you can join back to the other tables.

To get the latest two enrollments that meet these criteria:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by contact_id order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from enrollment e
     ) e join
     (select contact_id
      from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by contact_id order by start_date desc) as seqnum
            from enrollment e
           ) e
      where seqnum <= 2
      group by contact_id
      having min(productid) <> max(productid) or
             max(start_date) > dateadd(day, 1, min(start_date))
     ) ee
     on e.contact_id = ee.contact_id and e.seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Your answer was useful, but I found that using a table variable and inserting/updating the proper values was a faster way of manipulating the data (about 30s as opposed to several minutes with something akin to the above code).  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Contact CONT
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Enrollment.* FROM Enrollment WHERE Owning_Contact_ID = CONT.Contact_ID ORDER BY Start_date desc)
```

What columns have indexes?  Enrollment needs an index on Owning_Contact_ID and Start_date.